# Adding direction and lengths of semi-major axes of ellipses to their attribute tables in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, geometry, azimuth, ellipse

I made a polygon shapefile with hundreds of ellipses (using the ellipse tool). I want to know their orientations and the lengths of their semi-major and semi-minor axes (and add these to their attribute table), but I can't figure out how to generate this information. I thought it would be easy, as when I am creating an ellipse, I can specify these three inputs to make the ellipse.

Does anyone know how to do this, or a workaround?

My ultimate goal is to compare the aspect ratios of a bunch of geomorphic features and see what direction they are pointing. I drew the ellipses enclosing each of my features so that I could do all of these things at once.

Comment: I was able to reverse-engineer the parameters of geodesic ellipses from 12 vertices (without access to ArcPy). You can certainly do this if you try. It starts with locating the center point, and then the distance from that center to the point(s) farthest away and closest.